# NSURLRequest timeOut handling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timeout, nsurlrequest

I've been reading some issues here with NSURLRequest timeOut, but I see no answer to my problem.
Well, here it is: my NSURLRequest object works fine, but I need to show some alert to the user if the connection time out is higher to 3. And i dun know how to handle that timeout.
Any help is really appreciate it.

```
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:3] ;
[webView setDelegate:self];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a delegate for the web view --  add `<UIWebViewDelegate>` in the `@interface` definition of your view controller and then link it up in Interface builder

then add a method

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{

// whatever you want to do if it times out (or some other error)

}
```